# Java Regex: How to extract ip address except the last part from the string?

Tags: java, regex

I am experimenting with `websockets` and I want to make it connect to local network automatically from another computer on the `LAN` and since there are 255 possible computers on the same network I want it to try all and then connect to whichever it can connect to first. However, first part of an IP address, **192.168.1.***, is different based on router settings.

I can get the whole current IP address of the machine, then I want to extract the front part.

For example

```
25.0.0.5 will become 25.0.0.
192.168.0.156 will become 192.168.0.
192.168.1.5 will become 192.168.1.
```

and so on

```
 String Ip  = "123.345.67.1";
 //what do I do here to get IP == "123.345.67."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex for this:

```
String Ip  = "123.345.67.1";
String IpWithNoFinalPart  = Ip.replaceAll("(.*\\.)\\d+$", "$1");
System.out.println(IpWithNoFinalPart);
```

A quick regex explanation: `(.*\\.)` is a capturing group that holds all characters up to the last `.` (due to greedy matching with `*` quantifier),  `\\d+` matches 1 or several digits, and `$` is the end of string.

Here is a [sample program on TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWkEtZDRQcmVsUTA).

Answer (score 1):

```
String Ip  = "123.345.67.1";
String newIp = Ip.replaceAll("\\.\\d+$", "");
System.out.println(newIp);
```

Output:

```
123.345.67
```

---

Explanation:

```
\.\d+$

Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match a single character that is a “digit” «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any «$»
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/OZs6FY

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex you could make use of `String.lastIndexOf('.')` to find the last dot and `String.substring(...)` to extract the first part as follows:

```
String ip = "192.168.1.5";
System.out.println(ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
// prints 192.168.1.
```

Comment: This would fail if the number after the last dot is more than 9.

Comment: @OmarAli that's not true, it will work regardless of how many characters are behind the last dot

Answer (score -1):

Just split the string on the dot "." If the string is a valid IP Address string, then you should then have a String[] array with 4 parts, you can then join only the first 3 with a dot "." and have the "front part"

i.e.

```
    String IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    String[] parts = IPAddress.split(".");

    StringBuffer frontPart = new StringBuffer();
    frontPart.append(parts[0]).append(".")
             .append(parts[1]).append(".")
             .append(parts[2]).append(".");
```